# Mediapipe FACEMESH_IRISES coordinates

Tags: coordinates, mediapipe

I am using mediapipe to find coordinates of eye iris in an static image.
I have next code to do this.
At the end I run print('', face_landmarks) and I have all coordinates x,y,z.
If I run print('',mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_IRISES) I have only index of Iris points like next:

frozenset({(475, 476), (477, 474), (469, 470), (472, 469), (471, 472), (474, 475), (476, 477), (470, 471)})

How can I get coordinates instead of index of each Iris point?

```
from multiprocessing import connection
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import sys
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
IMAGE_FILES = [("pic1.jpg")]
drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
    static_image_mode=True,
    max_num_faces=1,
    refine_landmarks=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:
  for idx, file in enumerate(IMAGE_FILES):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    results = face_mesh.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    if not results.multi_face_landmarks:
      continue
    annotated_image = image.copy()
    for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
      mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
          image=annotated_image,
          landmark_list=face_landmarks,   
          connections=mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_IRISES,
          landmark_drawing_spec=None,
          connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
          .get_default_face_mesh_iris_connections_style())
      mp_face_mesh
```

Answer (score 1):

For mediapipe canonical index, from 0 to 467 are face landmarks and from 468 to 477 are iris landmarks. Assume index 468 and 473 are left and right iris center points. You can get their 3D coordinates with

```
(lm_left_iris.x, lm_left_iris.y, lm_left_iris.z) = face_landmarks.landmark[468]
(lm_right_iris.x, lm_right_iris.y, lm_right_iris.z) = face_landmarks.landmark[473]
```